# RSAT slow performance

Tags: windows-server-2003, windows-7, remote-access

We are running Win 7 SP1 RSAT with a Server 2003 DC.  We mainly use it to reset AD passwords.  The performance is extremely slow (one minute of non-responsiveness per password reset).  How do we improve the performance?

Comment: you should make sure that you do not have any configuration problems (especially in regards to DNS) with your domain. Also, for better troubleshooting, you should run [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/) on the W7 workstation capturing the network traffic while attempting the password reset and see where the holdup happens.

Answer (score 3):

There aren't really enough details here to give a definitive answer, so I'll share this nugget of knowledge:

If you have an AD problem, it's probably because of a DNS issue. If you checked DNS and you still have a problem, it's because you missed the DNS issue that's causing your problem.

Comment: "It's always DNS." - Because DNS is used for everything.